# Detect DIV resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, addeventlistener, window-resize

As you can't bind the resize event to anything else than the window, how can I add a resize event listener to a `.container` DIV?

So how to bind this to `$('.container')`?

```
$(window).on('resize', this.limitWrapperHeight.bind(this));
```

Comment: How are you resizing the element? If you're using a library, such as jQueryUI, it raises events on resize.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The images within the div are lazyloaded so the container sometimes changes its height while scrolling. But binding the event to a scroll listener would be very inefficient.

Comment: What causes the resize? User interaction or content change?

Comment: @charlietfl Content change

Comment: Try throttling scroll event handler.

Comment: Why don't you bind this to a lazyload event? What lazyload library are you using?

Comment: @KHansen Lazysizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stated in the [Documentation](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/gh-pages/README.md):

```
document.addEventListener('lazyloaded', function(e){
  console.log("Image is loaded");
});
```